# Google Sheets RegexpReplace with computable replacers

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regex-group, array-formulas

I'm trying to replace a pattern with some string computed with other GSheets functions. For example, I want to make all the int numbers in the string ten times larger: *"I want to multiply 2 numbers in this string by 10"* should turn into *"I want to multiply 20 numbers in this string by 100"*.

Assuming for short, that my string is in **A1** cell, I've tried a construction

```
REGEXREPLACE(A1, "([0-9]+)", TEXT(10*VALUE("$1"),"###"))
```

But it seems REGEXREPLACE firstly computes the arguments and only after that yields regular expression rules. So it converts **3rd** argument

```
TEXT(10*VALUE("$1"),"###") => TEXT(10*1,"###") => "10"
```

and then just replaces all integers in the string with 10.
It turns out, I need to substitute the group **$1** BEFORE implementing outer functions in the 3rd argument. Is there any way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's another way. See if this works

```
=join(" ", ArrayFormula(if(isnumber(split(A1, " ")), split(A1, " ")*10, split(A1, " "))))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ", IFERROR(SPLIT(A1, " ")*10, SPLIT(A1, " "))))
```

[image: 0]

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ", IF(ISNUMBER(SPLIT(A1, " ")), SPLIT(A1, " ")*10, SPLIT(A1, " "))))
```